# get index with a specified key for map in C++

Tags: c++, stl

```
map<int, int> m;
m[-1]=1;   
m[45]=100;
m[20]=3;
// -1<20<45. So The index of (-1, 1) is 0; (45, 100) is 2; (20, 3) is 1;
// "find" function returns the iterator, but how to know its order? 
number = m.find(45) - m.begin(); // This is apparently not correct.
```

How to find the index once known a key in map?

Comment: What are you trying to solve? Why do you need an index into a map?

Comment: I will need the index as the local ID which further will be written into a file.

Comment: `std::distance` will probably do what you want, not that it will do much good, as I still don't see what the point is. the "index" is the key; that's the very point of a map.

Comment: Are you trying to write the complete map into a file?

Comment: Almost @JollyJose .

Comment: @TerryQiao, Iteration is the best way to dump the values to file in the order and map don't support the pre and post order traversals like actual Balanced Binary Tree. std::distance is the option to find the distance of position of the element from beginning or arbitrary iterator position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no indices in maps, only iterators.

To get the iterator, you can do:

```
std::map<int, int>::iterator it = m.find(45);
```

If you really want to find the "distance", you can do the following:

```
auto dist = std::distance(m.begin(),m.find(45));
```